# Are there any functions to search with keywords or categorize my thousands of bookmarked questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, search, bookmarks

Although the bookmark function can save my favorite questions, it is still a mess since I have bookmarked thousands of questions for a long time.

Comment: See also: [How to search in favorite questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8995)

Comment: There were also a few discussions related to organizing favorites. but I'm not sure that you can find there some satisfactory suggestion:
[Tips for organizing one's own favorites?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3251),
[Managing favourites](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3639),
[Multiple Favourites Lists](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26399),
[Organizing favorite posts in folders\categories](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28907),
[Is it possible to group somehow questions I've asked in the past?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29714). You can also ....

Comment: ... upvote a similar feature request on [meta.se]: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there's an [advanced search option](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for this: just add `inbookmarks:mine` to your search query.

You can even search within another user's bookmarks; I don't have any bookmarks on the main site, so when I search for [`inbookmarks:mine integration`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=inbookmarks%3Amine+integration) I get no results, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=inbookmarks%3A83346+integration) must be the results you get:

[image]

The ability to group them has been requested (a couple of times): [Allow grouping of favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125180/295232) but it doesn't seem the company wants to spend time on this. You can combine bookmark search with tags, and if you want to categorize them in a different way, there's always the option to use your browser's bookmark function.

Comment: I remember this Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey on Stack Apps: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/q/6215). However, when I tried installed it, it did not work for me. (It was some time ago - of course, it is possible that I was doing something wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

I keep two text files at home, here are selections. I group them by what I see as the topic.  ANYONE  can do this.  Sometimes an OP wants lots of examples in a topic I have frequently answered. I just copy a relevant section and paste into an answer window, say it is too long for a comment and make it CW.

```
Vieta Jumping/ Hurwitz/Markov         Grundl&ouml;sung
 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115272/let-x-and-y-be-positive-integers-such-that-xy-mid-x2y21?rq=1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632097/diophantine-quartic-equation-in-four-variables/632178#632178
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829228/is-it-true-that-fx-y-dfracx2y2xy-t-has-only-finitely-many-distinct-i/1480206#1480206  !!!!!!!!!  +++++++  
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411049/if-a-b-are-positive-integers-and-ab-1-mid-a%C2%B2-b%C2%B2-then-prove-that-q  
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415252/proving-that-all-terms-in-sequence-are-positive-integers-recursive/1415304#1415304
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417404/diophantine-equation-xyxy1-kxy-0
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462435/find-the-postive-integers-such-xyxy-mid-x2y2-2
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478289/find-the-integer-values-of-c
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604292/find-all-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-x2y2z2-xyz22/1604582#1604582
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780420/characterize-the-integers-a-b-satisfying-ab-1a2b2/1781381#1781381
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930438/equation-with-vieta-jumping-xyz2-nxyz/1930796#1930796     Follows Hurwitz very closely!!  (x+y+z)^2 = nxyz   
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188567/showing-that-m2-n21-is-a-square/2193043#2193043  LEMMA + 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188567/showing-that-m2-n21-is-a-square/2193944#2193944   LEMMA -
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399830/how-prove-infinitely-many-postive-integers-triples-x-y-z-such-xyz22x/2400509#2400509  
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664145/find-all-possible-value-of-c/2668331#2668331 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818849/what-are-the-solutions-of-the-equation-3np3n2-n2p2-with-n-and-p-positive/2818883#2818883
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853669/prove-there-is-no-x-y-in-mathbb-z-text-satisfying-fracxy-fracy/2853742#2853742
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869251/integer-points-on-a-hyperbola/2869365#2869365 two spiral arms 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955986/mnp-1-2-sqrtmnp-in-positive-integers
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1726220_if_fraction_integer_then_equal_to_5   Poland 1991 training


     Pell
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864263/find-general-solution-for-the-equation-1-2-cdots-n-%E2%88%92-1-n-1-n/1864611#1864611
    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424587/when-is-5n214n1-a-perfect-square/2424599#2424599  x^2 - 5 y^2 =44
    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546839/state-2-values-of-x-for-which-the-value-of-3x24x-14-is-a-perfect-square/2546875#2546875
       x^2 - 3 y^2 = 46
    
    TOPOGRAPH 
    RIVERBEND PROOF:
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342284/generate-solutions-of-quadratic-diophantine-equation/346821#346821
    diagrams
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81917/another-quadratic-diophantine-equation-how-do-i-proceed/144794#144794
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228356/how-to-find-solutions-of-x2-3y2-2/228405#228405
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342284/generate-solutions-of-quadratic-diophantine-equation/345128#345128
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487051/why-cant-the-alpertron-solve-this-pell-like-equation/487063#487063
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512621/finding-all-solutions-of-the-pell-type-equation-x2-5y2-4/512649#512649
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680972/if-m-n-in-mathbb-z-2-satisfies-3m2m-4n2n-then-m-n-is-a-perfect-square/686351#686351
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739752/how-to-solve-binary-form-ax2bxycy2-m-for-integer-and-rational-x-y/739765#739765  ::::  69   55
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742181/find-all-integer-solutions-for-the-equation-5x2-y2-4/756972#756972
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822503/positive-integer-n-such-that-2n1-3n1-are-both-perfect-squares/822517#822517
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078450/maps-of-primitive-vectors-and-conways-river-has-anyone-built-this-in-sage/1078979#1078979
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091310/infinitely-many-systems-of-23-consecutive-integers/1093382#1093382
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132187/solve-the-following-equation-for-x-and-y/1132347#1132347  <1,-1,-1>
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132799/finding-integers-of-the-form-3x2-xy-5y2-where-x-and-y-are-integers
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221178/small-integral-representation-as-x2-2y2-in-pells-equation/1221280#1221280
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404023/solving-the-equation-x2-7y2-3-over-integers/1404126#1404126
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599211/solutions-to-diophantine-equations/1600010#1600010
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667323/how-to-prove-that-the-roots-of-this-equation-are-integers/1667380#1667380
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719280/does-the-pell-like-equation-x2-dy2-k-have-a-simple-recursion-like-x2-dy2
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737385/if-d1-is-a-squarefree-integer-show-that-x2-dy2-c-gives-some-bounds-i/1737824#1737824 "seeds"
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772594/find-all-natural-numbers-n-such-that-21n2-20-is-a-perfect-square/1773319#1773319
    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549380/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-if-b-aba-ab-1-then-a-b-must-be-fibon/2549440#2549440 1,1,-1; 1,11
    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579293/to-find-all-integral-solutions-of-3x2-4y2-11/2579305#2579305
    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778825/how-do-we-solve-pell-like-equations/3778953#3778953
    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804117/diophantine-equation-x2-xy-%e2%88%92-3y2-17/3804236#3804236 <1,1,-3>
    
    http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf   (Conway) 
    https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNbook.pdf    (Hatcher)
    http://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/                  (Weissman)
    http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387955872             (Stillwell)
```